# Noise when using AVAudioEngine over HDMI

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

I am using AVAudioSession with playAndRecord category as follows:

```
   private func setupAudioSessionForRecording() {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    
    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(false)
        try audioSession.setPreferredSampleRate(Double(48000))

    } catch {
        NSLog("Unable to deactivate Audio session")
    }
    
    let options:AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions = [.allowAirPlay, .mixWithOthers]
    
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: options)
    } catch {
        NSLog("Could not set audio session category \(error)")
    }
    
    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        NSLog("Unable to activate AudioSession")
    }
   
}
```

Next I use AVAudioEngine to repeat what I speak in the microphone to external speakers (on the TV connected with iPhone using HDMI Cable).

```
    //MARK:- AudioEngine

var engine: AVAudioEngine!
var playerNode: AVAudioPlayerNode!
var mixer: AVAudioMixerNode!
var audioEngineRunning = false

public func setupAudioEngine() {
    
    self.engine = AVAudioEngine()
    
    engine.connect(self.engine.inputNode, to: self.engine.outputNode, format: nil)
    
    do {
        engine.prepare()
        try self.engine.start()
    }
    catch {
        print("error couldn't start engine")
    }
    
    audioEngineRunning = true
}

public func stopAudioEngine() {
    engine.stop()
    audioEngineRunning = false
}
```

The issue is I hear some kind of reverb/humming noise after I speak for a few seconds that keeps getting amplified and repeated. If I use a RemoteIO unit instead, no such noise comes out of speakers. I am not sure if my setup of AVAudioEngine is correct. I have tried all kinds of AVAudioSession configuration but nothing changes.

Here is a [link](http://sndup.net/pgqv) to audio demonstrating background speaker noise. It's akin to DTMF noise that keeps growing with time, I don't know. But you can listen to the audio to better understand the source of the noise.

Comment: Not sure if it'll work over HDMI, but have you tried `engine.inputNode.setVoiceProcessingEnabled(true)` ?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman If I set that, nothing comes out of input node. I think that it disables Airplay. Also have a look at the link I shared having audio recording.